# How to automatically run crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Once a week I need to run a bunch of Crystal Reports and then email them. I want to know if there's a way to run them automatically? I've tried using Crystal-Delivery, but for some reason it only runs the reports that don't have parameters.

Has anyone used Crystal-Delivery before and have a solution for my problems? Their forum is not very helpful. Or is there other software that can do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are various solutions, including Crystal Delivery which I have used successfully with reports with parameters. After adding the report double click, and complete the "parameters" tab.

Comment: Well, I did add parameters in that tab, but it just runs for hours and doesn't do anything. What other software are there?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways one can skin this. There are various options to build a pdf from a given report (if you're building in java for instance) and one can fairly easily run the java on a cron, and then have a mail script running on cron to send out those files once they've been created (that mail script could be in php or java or whatever takes your fancy).